# ListView is not working in android activity and throwing missing resource ID error of textView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I am new in android development and trying to use ListView in my simple app. But it is not working and throwing error.

Here is the code of  **DisplayMessageActivity.java**. I have created a String Array and putted value manually. I am calling resource ID using what we call custom adapter.

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String[] mobileArray={"A", "B"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String message=intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);
        System.out.println("seq");
        ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_display_message, R.id.listView, mobileArray);
        System.out.println("seq2");
        ListView listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        System.out.println("seq3");
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        System.out.println("seq44");
    }
}
```

XML of **activity_display_message.xml** is below where I created one ListView.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Error log**

```
09-06 15:00:43.859 3751-3751/? E/ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
09-06 15:00:43.859 3751-3751/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-06 15:00:43.860 3751-3751/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 3751
                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:393)
                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1280)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:389)
                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369) 
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346) 
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1280) 
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188) 
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715) 
                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461) 
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135) 
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391) 
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) 
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465) 
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748) 
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630) 
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643) 
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013) 
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858) 
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670) 
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606) 
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: you can not access the adaptor textview in activity 
create  custom adaptor search on google custom listview.

Comment: Passing a wrong layout for adapter, "activity_display_message"

Comment: @ashok Try this ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mobileArray);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you are newbie, try android predefined layout.

To do that you just need to edit your adapter like below.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mobileArray);
```

***let me know if you have any question about this solution.***

Comment: do I need to create a new simple_list_item_1.xml file for List?

Answer (score 0):

create a new layout for lite view row item like this

list_item_type_1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_type1_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_type1_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text goes here" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**than create adapter class like this**

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public MyCustomAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public void addItem(final String item) {
            mData.add(item);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
          if(position < LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1_COUNT)
              return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1;
          else
              return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return mData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            int type = getItemViewType(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_type1, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_type1_text_view);

            holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }

    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
    }

}
```

**[check this listview demo](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)**

**than set adapter to your listview**

Answer (score 0):

Please read closely to what the stacktrace says:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

In your code you are trying to pass a listView here, which should be the instance of TextView

ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_display_message, R.id.listView, mobileArray);

Comment: Is it not possible to access ListView from a relative layout that have combination of different views? I thought for an activity, only one XML file is sufficient and we can use any number of views in that.

Comment: As far as I understand from the stacktrace. The probleim is not in accessing to a proper ListView but with an instantiation of an ArrayAdapter. Please see the link to check the concstructor you are trying to use while instantiatin the ArrayAdapter.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, int, java.util.List<T>)